# Wolf GPU miner using CPU?

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining, mining-software

I downloaded Wolfs OpenCL miner ([github](https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner)) and made a .bat file to start it. I noticed that it uses the CPU as well (and on the cmd output it says Capeverde 200h/s and then 50 h/s for 2 cpu cores total 300h/s). When using the miner the CPU usage gets to 50%. How can i disable the CPU mining? Maybe pass something from the .bat file? Im using windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration is done  in the file "xmr.conf".

Index "-1" is used for the CPU.

You can disable CPU mining by setting  **"threads": 0** in the section with **"index": -1**

Comment: This is all noted in the README.md.

Answer (score 3):

Open up the xmr.conf file in a text editor such as notepad.

Edit the part which says "index": -1 as follows, changing the thread count from the default of 2 to 0:

```
"index": -1,
"threads": 0,
"rawintensity": 16
"worksize": 16
```

A screenshot of an example .conf file is below, with the highlighted change.

[image: xmr.conf]